# ML-inequality: Why does this hold $|e^{-3y+3ix}| = e^{-3y}$ during numerator estimation of $f(z) = \frac{e^{3iz}}{z^2 + 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Given the following related to an ML-inequality for $R > 1$:

[image: given data]

Estimation of the numerator from the function $f(z)$ is supposed to develop as follows:

[image: estimation of the numerator]

I'm wondering why and how exactly the power $3ix$ cancels out (why does it vanish/equal to zero) in the equality $|e^{-3y+3ix}| = e^{-3y}$ ?

Comment: $|e^{3ix}|=|\cos 3x+i\sin 3x|=1$ ?

Comment: aaah yeah thanks, definitely answers the question, how can we mark this as duplicate and solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=\alpha+\beta i$ be a complex number. Then
\begin{align}
|e^z| &= |e^{\alpha +\beta i}|\\
&=|e^{\alpha}e^{\beta i}|\\
&=|e^\alpha| |e^{\beta i}|\\
&=e^\alpha|\cos\beta +i\sin\beta|\\
&=e^\alpha\sqrt{\cos^2\beta +\sin^2\beta}\\
&=e^\alpha\cdot \sqrt{1}\\
&=e^\alpha.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$, so $|e^{ix}| = \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$.